# React Native setinterval Memory Leak

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, setinterval, setstate

I have a memory leak for a simple timer using a setInterval (I have similar functions with the same problem and I am using this to debug) with this set up in React Native.  I do not know how to stop this leak but the memory stair-steps up over time as the interval runs and does not release when the interval stops (i.e. moving to a different screen/component).

The state is setting and I am returning some time variation (it is not perfectly formatted but that is not the point).

```
const [ currentTime, setCurrentTime ] = useState( 240 );

    const tick = useCallback( () => {
        if ( !!currentTime ) setCurrentTime( currentTime - 1 );
    }, [ currentTime, setCurrentTime ] );
    
    
    useEffect( () => {
        const timer = setInterval( tick, 1000 );
        return () => clearInterval( timer );
    }, [ currentTime ] );
    

    const TimerClass =()=>{
        return( <Text style={gstyles.bigText}>{currentTime / 60 +":0" + ( currentTime % 60 ) }</Text>)
    }
```

I have implemented clean up methods on my useeffect (`return () => clearInterval( timer );`) which seems to be the consensus online.  However, I am still getting a memory leak.  I think this degrading the overall performance of the app over time because the memory is shooting through the roof and not releasing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have just experienced a very similar issue, hopefully this helps in some way.

This is only relevant if you are using `@react-navigation/native`. Otherwise feel  free to mark this as unhelpful.

There is a difference in the way @react-navigation/native routing works compared to React routing. The problem is that when the navigation goes to a different page it doesn't unmount the previous page/route and instead holds that in memory.

Therefore the  `() => clearInterval( timer );` is never run.

The response here shows how you can structure it so that it does clean up correctly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70110451

I'm not sure if it entirely solves the problem, but at least you should be able to clear the interval now.